# How do I make a jQuery Mobile page slide happen with a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery-mobile, slide, jquery, swipe

jQuery function (works on its own):

```
$("#firstpage").live('pageinit', function (evt) {
    $("#firstpage").bind("swipeleft", function (e) {
        alert ("you swiped left!");
    });
});
```

jQuery mobile link (also works on its own):

```
<a href="#secondpage" data-transition="slide">GO TO PAGE 2</a>
```

So how do I combine the two? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `$.mobile.changePage()` method.

Check Jquery mobile Doc
 http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html

```
$("#firstpage").live('pageinit', function (evt) {
    $("#firstpage").bind("swipeleft", function (e) {
       $.mobile.changePage("#secondpage", { transition : 'slide'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Not quite as responsive as a native app for obvious reasons, but still useful.

Comment: @orbwhacker If you want responsive you can achieve it, but you have to use `touchstart`/`touchmove`/`touchend`. Check-out swipejs.com, it's some slick code. The jQuery Mobile events, `swipeleft`/`swiperight`, just are not responsive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.mobile.changePage()`, it's what is used internally to transition between pages. Here is an example:

```
$(document).delegate("#firstpage", 'pageinit', function (evt) {
    $(this).bind("swipeleft", function (e) {
        $.mobile.changePage("#secondpage", {
            transition : 'slide'
        });
    });
}).delegate("#secondpage", 'pageinit', function (evt) {
    $(this).bind("swiperight", function (e) {
        $.mobile.changePage("#firstpage", {
            transition : 'slide',
            reverse    : true
        });
    });
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QjUMh/

Check-out the documentation for `$.mobile.changePage` and see all the options it has: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html